# How to calculate time in HH:mm:ss format from array

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I m trying to calculate time from an array where time is stored in HH:mm:ss format, i m making time array from this code,

```
$result=[];
foreach ($playerTimes as $playerTime) {
    $playerStartTime = (isset($playerTime->start_time))? $playerTime->start_time: '00:00:00';
    $playerEndTime = (isset($playerTime->End_time))? $playerTime->End_time: '00:00:00';
    $result[] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($playerStartTime)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($playerEndTime))->format('%H:%I:%S');

                          }
```

and I get this array

```
array:3 [0 => "08:44:14" 1 => "10:46:16" 2 => "12:48:18"]
```

the result I m trying to achieve after the addition is `32:18:48`

I have tried this, however the result I got is `08:18:48` which is not what i need,

```
$result[] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($playerStartTime)->diffInSeconds(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($playerEndTime));
dd(gmdate("H:i:s", array_sum($result)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the `H:i:s` format does just not support what you are trying to achieve here, as `H` can never be greater than 23, nor smaller than 0.

There are two possible solutions: you can use `Y-m-d H:i:s`, to show the difference in years, months and days also, or you can use these values to convert them back to hours, or calculate the hours from the seconds difference (so seconds difference / 60 / 60 = hours), and work from there.

Comment: Thank you for the hint , I have solved this, I didn't know that H can not be larger than 23,I convert time into seconds and then seconds into hours , minutes and second.